# Better way to write the minimum cost covering formula

Tags: align, alignment, research

I'm trying to reproduce the model for the minimum cost covering that follows:

[image]

I managed to do this:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    \text{min}  & \sum_{i \in I} C_i x_i \\
        s.t.\\
                & \sum_{i \in I} A_{ij}x_i \ge D_j \qquad\qquad \forall j \in J\\
                & x_i \in \mathbb{R}_+ [ \mathbb{Z}_+ | \{0,1\} ]\qquad \forall i \in I
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem with this is that it doesn't seems right to me. 
It looks like I'm using the wrong package or the wrong environment to redo this piece of formula

Comment: you don't really say what you want to change, mainly I'd use `\mid` not `|` to get a better spaced |  your first image aligns the forall, I'd align them or use `\quad` on both you have used quad on one and qquad on the other.

Comment: Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, if use of `alignat` environment gives nicer result:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
\min\quad & \sum_{i \in I} C_i x_i \\
\text{s.t.}\quad        &   &   &\\
            & \sum_{i \in I} A_{ij}x_i \ge D_j               
                        & \forall j & \in J\\
            & x_i \in \mathbb{R}_+ [\mathbb{Z}_+ \mid \{0,1\} ] 
                \qquad  & \forall i & \in I
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edidt:**
You may prefer to have less space between `\min` and `\text{s.t.}` and `summ` signs. At this case you remove `\quad`s before ampersands:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
\min        & \sum_{i \in I} C_i x_i \\
\text{s.t.} &   &   &\\
            & \sum_{i \in I} A_{ij}x_i \ge D_j
                        & \forall j & \in J\\
            & x_i \in \mathbb{R}_+ [\mathbb{Z}_+ \mid \{0,1\} ]
                \qquad  & \forall i & \in I
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**
One more solution as suggested @Sebastiano in his comment (than you very much Sebastiano!) with dedicated package `optidef`. You may liked it :-) :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}
\begin{mini}
{i}{\sum_{i\in I} C_i x_i}
{\label{eq:Example1}}{}
\addConstraint{\sum_{i \in I} A_{ij}x_i \ge D_j &\qquad}{\forall j \in J}
\addConstraint{x_i \in \mathbb{R}_+ [\mathbb{Z}_+ \mid \{0,1\})}{&\forall i  \in I.}
\end{mini}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is certainly much better than what I wrote, but it seems to me that something is still missing.
For example, I don't understand how that "space" between the min and the summation was written.

Comment: @LukeTheWolf, you can delete this two `\quad`s. I make some experiments what is looking better and on the end I didn't delete them. Now I added version without `\quad`s ...

Comment: Hi from the hospital very kind. I suggest optidef package in addendum.

Comment: @Sebastiano, are you in hospital? If yes, I wish you fast recovering! My addendum I will write ASAP.

Comment: Carissimo. All ok.☺️. In optidef package there is also the option min and s.t.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for these hints: that was exactly what I was looking for. @Sebastiano riprenditi presto, mi raccomando! Woooof

Comment: @LukeTheWolf thank you very very muchhhhhhhhhhhhh